# How to provide dagger dependency for other fragments?

Tags: android, dagger-2

I have `ApplicationComponent` that provides `ApiModule` and others

```
@PerApplicationScope
@Component(
        modules = {ApiModule.class, ApplicationModule.class}
)
public interface ApplicationComponent {

    void inject(MainActivity activity);
}
```

I'm building this component on the start of the application as such:

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    component = DaggerApplicationComponent.builder()
            .applicationModule(new ApplicationModule(this))
            .apiModule(new ApiModule())
            .build();
}
```

Only after my initial fragment loads and I get response from certain API response I can create `Player` that should be shared across all other fragments.

How can I tell Dagger that there is new module with new dependency?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Dagger you can play with components scopes, if you want the same instance of a Object across the app life cycle your dependencies must be provided as a @Singleton in Application level component.

You can create your custom scopes, for an Activity of Fragment using custom annotations to provides de same instance of ApiModule dependencies in that graph lifecycle.

Here there is a sample project that plays with Dagger scopes

https://github.com/joesteele/dagger2-component-scopes-test

And here a great post about this topic

http://fernandocejas.com/2015/04/11/tasting-dagger-2-on-android/